# How do I flatten a list from a database (mongodb) in python?

Tags: python, mongodb, list

I am storing a simple list in mongodb -

`{'tags': ["vegetarian", "kosher", "gluten-free"]}`

Using python how would I best fetch this list and flatten it?
Thus far every attempt I have made using 2-3 different flattening methods still append like:

`{'tags': [["vegetarian", "kosher", "gluten-free"], "appended item"]}`

and this gets a step worse with each fetch and append. I do not want to simply append it into the document, as I still need the flattened list for other functions.

I have tried:

```
def read_tags(cls):
    cls.__connect()
    result = list(cls.__tags.find({}, {"tags": 1, "_id": 0}))
    flat_result = [item for sublist in result for item in sublist]
    return flat_result
```

and

```
def read_tags(cls):
    cls.__connect()
    tag_list = []
    result = list(cls.__tags.find({}, {"tags": 1, "_id": 0}))
    for item in result:
        tag_list.append(item)
    return tag_list
```

The results are always that the initial list remains nested and each addition further layers the list until I end up with:

```
{'tags': [[[[previously_stored_list], appended_item1], appended_item2], appended_item3]}
```

when what I want to have is:

```
["vegetarian", "kosher", "gluten-free", "appended_item1", "appended_item2", "appended_item3"]
```

Comment: Which python package are you using to connect to MongoDB?

Comment: So you want a list of all `"tags"` in the collection?  Do you want the distinct `"tags"` or do you want everything with possible repeats?

Comment: Eric - I'm using Pymongo
Rick - Either? I'm making a small side app to add and remove these tags from a list. so hypothetically if there's a duplicate that would be on the user to sort. If you have an opinion on which I should do I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by simply changing the return value to

```
            return item['tags']
```